# Unlock gnome keyring from systemd service using PAM

Tags: systemd, pam, gnome-keyring

Is it possible to unlock the gnome keyring using PAM when running
as a systemd service?

Our software uses Python Keyring module to store credentials, but I am
having trouble using the SecretService Keyring backend on RHEL/Centos
because it requires you to pass the keyring password to gnome_keyring_daemon.

From https://pypi.org/project/keyring/:

```
    Install the GNOME Keyring daemon.

    Start a D-Bus session, e.g. run dbus-run-session -- sh and run the following commands inside that shell.

    Run gnome-keyring-daemon with --unlock option. The description of that option says:

        Read a password from stdin, and use it to unlock the login keyring or create it if the login keyring does not exist.

    When that command is started, enter your password into stdin and press Ctrl+D (end of data). After that the daemon will fork into background (use --foreground option to prevent that).

    Now you can use the SecretService backend of Keyring. Remember to run your application in the same D-Bus session as the daemon.
```

I am able to access the gnome keyring (and the credentials) when running as a systemd
service as described above using a script with the keyring password
harded coded like this:

```
dbus-run-session -- "./unlock-keyring-run.sh"
```

Where unlock-keyring-run.sh looks like this:

```
echo "Passw0rd" | gnome-keyring-daemon --unlock
run_my_program
```

I am wondering if PAM will allow the gnome keyring to be unlocked when the systemd service starts so that I don't have to (insecurely)
pass it in the script.  There is documentation for using PAM to unlock the keyring on when logging in from a console:

https://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/GnomeKeyring/Pam/Manual

I'm wondering if the gnome keyring PAM directives work for 
/etc/pam.d/systemd-user ?